# PDF-images -> slow scrolling

Tags: graphics, pdf

I use LaTeX for writing my Thesis.

I recently added 7 pdf-images rendered in matlab. These images are placed one after another. When I scroll over this part of the thesis in pdfTex or Apple Preview it slow down disturbingly. Especially because I will add a lot more of these images.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I would suppose that it is because of the size of the images and dependent on your pdf reader. What you can do is insert a dummy diagram and continue with your thesis. In the end then you can input the diagrams to check that everything looks good.

Comment: If I would have to bet, I would bet that you plotted something like 20,000 datapoints in a plot because it was convenient to do so and then exported as eps or pdf. If you want to speed everything up, export the image from matlab as png at the correct size or decrease the number of datapoits

Comment: Thx!! You guys are right, it is a plot with A LOT of data points. I didn't know this has it's effects after I exported it to a vector-based image.

Comment: Use the `draft` option while writing your paper and remove it for the final version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the images probably contain very complicated vector graphics. Sometimes it might be better to convert them to raster graphics. If you have `ImageMagick` installed, then you can do it by

```
convert -resize 2400 drawing.pdf drawing.png
```

The number `2400` is given by `<desired-resolution-in-dpi>*<resulting-width-in-inches>`, where I thought of `600dpi*4in=2400px`.

For a draft or soft-copy (= for screen, not for printing) version of your paper you can arbitrarily lower this number of course to get a "faster" result.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend it

```
convert -density 300 drawing.pdf drawing.png
```

The density 300 means the resolution or dots per inch(DPI).
If you are not satisfied for image resolution, try it for 600 DPI.

Comment: Takes a long time - but the images look great that way. Thanks!